# Add break line before pattern

Tags: javascript

I have the following text:

```
const text = 'ABC: 12345431237 ZXQ: 123QQ123112 I/a: /123123123 ASDHAJKSD ASJDAKD AHSJDKASD'
```

I need add a breakline before 'xxx:' (three characters followed by a colon)

the result should be like this:

```
ABC: 12345431237
ZXQ: 123QQ123112 
I/a: /123123123 ASDHAJKSD ASJDAKD AHSJDKASD
```

I guess the best solution is replace the pattern with a regex.

Anyone know how to do it?

Comment: It would be best if you could include what you've tried that hasn't worked....

Comment: Also, that string does not contain "xxx:". Perhaps you could be clearer about what exactly "x" stands for in that pattern. For instance, does "I/a:" match?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To add the breakline before any three repeating characters followed by a : you can do the following.

```
var text = 'ABC: 12345431237 ZXQ: 123QQ123112 I/a: /123123123 ASDHAJKSD ASJDAKD AHSJDKASD';
// This also breaks before 'I/a:'
text = text.replace(/\s([\S]{3}:)/g, '\n$1');
```

Comment: `/\s([\S]{3}:)/g` - no need of trim

Comment: @User863 Oops, that's definitely better.